# How to fail Jenkins build if no tests were run?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, gradle, testng

We are running `TestNG` tests using `Gradle` on `Jenkins`.

Job configuration:
*Build section -> Invoke Gradle Script -> Use Gradle Wrapper -> Tasks:*

```
clean test -Dgroups=myTestNGTestGroupName
```

In `Jenkins` Console Output I can see the logs from execution of `gradlew.bat` with specific parameters (one of them is `-Dgroups=myTestNGTestGroupName`)).

We have quite a lot of `Jenkins` jobs and automation `Selenium` tests.
Since that on daily basis we are checking only failed jobs.

During refactoring tests `TestNG` group name may be changed or typo may occur.
If you changed the test group name in test repository and forgot to update `Jenkins` job:
**0** tests are executed and job is still passing (**build is successful**).

How can I tell `Jenkins` to mark build as non-successful if no tests were executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TestNG` generates `testng-results.xml` file every time after test run
(even if 0 tests were executed).

We can analyze this file. The simplest solution which I found is using
[Text-finder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin)
(which in my case was already added to `Jenkins`)

I added `Jenkins Text Finder` in `Post-build Actions` as follow:
[image: text-finder-plugin]

How it looks in `Jenkins` Console Output logs:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 42.105 secs
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
Archiving artifacts
Checking <testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" total="0" passed="0">
c:\jenkins\workspace\my-job-name\build\reports\tests\testng-results.xml:
<testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" total="0" passed="0">
Build step 'Jenkins Text Finder' changed build result to UNSTABLE
...
Finished: UNSTABLE
```